# Apply same transform() to mutiple columns in pandas without for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The code below works but just wondering whether this could be done without the for loop?

```
data = {'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-01','2023-01-01', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-03'],
        'p1': [5000, 7000, 6421, 9851, 1385, 1475],
        'p2': [22000, 27000, 25000, 29000, 35000, 1257]
        }

df_orig = pd.DataFrame(data)


def norm_std(x):
    return (x- np.mean(x))/np.std(x)



def s_d(df, c):
    df[c] = df.groupby('Date')[c].transform(norm_std)


for c in df_orig.columns[]:
    s_d(df_orig, c)
```

Comment: What is the name of the column you're excluding here: `df_orig.columns[1:]`?

Comment: post a testable `df_orig` fragment

Comment: df_orig.columns[0] has non numeric data, it's not that important to the problem so I have omitted it in the testable fragment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` and `difference` to exclude the `Date` column from `apply`:

```
exclude_col = "Date"
valid_cols = df_orig.columns.difference([exclude_col])
date_groupby = df_orig.groupby('Date')
df_orig[valid_cols] = df_orig[valid_cols].apply(lambda x: date_groupby[x.name].transform(norm_std))
```

df_orig:

```
         Date        p1        p2
0  2023-01-01 -1.357104 -1.297771
1  2023-01-01  1.023084  1.135550
2  2023-01-01  0.334020  0.162221
3  2023-01-03  1.414153  0.493108
4  2023-01-03 -0.718412  0.901328
5  2023-01-03 -0.695741 -1.394436
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `norm_std` works on dataframe with same index as the original, you can use `apply`:

```
df_orig.groupby('Date').apply(norm_std)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of posiible solutions is:

```
df_orig.iloc[:, 1:] = df_orig.groupby('Date').transform(norm_std)
```

*s_d* function is not needed.

Other possibility:

```
df_orig = df_orig.set_index('Date').groupby('Date').transform(norm_std).reset_index()
```

To silence a *FutureWarning* define *norm_std* as:

```
def norm_std(x):
    return (x - np.mean(x, axis=0))/np.std(x)
```